# Java Can l import a class to another class?

Tags: java, inheritance, import, package

l want to use variables from one class to another. How can l achieve this? I dont want to inherit from the other class. Is there any way to import the class / use package maybe? Haven't used packages yet so l dont know how they work.

(Using InteliJ Idea)

l am talking about classes made by us not already existing. Example - l make class Person and class Commands and l want to use fields from class Person in class Commands. I can't extend it because the user shouldn't be able to getID() in the Commands class. How can l get the fields in the Person class without inheriting?

Comment: Well "import" would be more of a term related to working with packages so you do don't have to use fully qualified names. I assume you mean access instances of other classes and the answer would be: yes, you can. You might want to grab a tutorial or revisit one but you could try passing those instances as parameters to constructors or methods.

Comment: Your question is too vague. Yes, you can obviously use other classes in your class (almost all classes do that). So you either need to read a general Java tutorial or show us the concrete use case that you're trying to solve. We won't just reproduce a whole tutorial full of information for you here.

Comment: l am talking about classes made by us not already existing. Example - l make class Person and class Commands and l want to use fields from class Person in class Commands. I can't extend it because the user shouldn't be able to getID of the Commands class. How can l get the fields in the Person class without inheriting?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating an instance variable in the class that you want to use this instance variable, Although, the class must be declared public to be available to all other packages, and make an import of the package where the class resides

Comment: this is actually a great idea! I will try it! Thanks a lot!